# What is netstat -r command used for?What does the different flags mean: MSS, window, etc

Tags: netstat

What does the different flags mean: MSS, window, etc

Comment: See `man netstat`. Your 2nd question is "tell me about networking", and too broad. Search Wikipedia

Answer (score 2):

From [`man netstat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/netstat.8.html):

```
--route , -r
   Display  the kernel routing tables. See the description in route(8) for
   details.  netstat -r and route -e produce the same output.
```

From [`man 8 route`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/route.8.html):

```
MSS    Default  maximum  segment  size  for  TCP  connections over this
       route.

Window Default window size for TCP connections over this route.
```